# How to convert properties to JSON the Spring MVC way?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I need my web service to serve me the messages.properties which contains localized texts in JSON format. I know that I can write my own parser to do that but where should I insert this logic in the Spring framework? Or is there a Spring infrastructure feature that already can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@PropertySource` annotation on your class to load your property file into memory.

```
@Configuration
class MessagesConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "messageProperties")
    public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("messages.properties"));
        return bean;
    }

    @Resource(name="messageProperties")
    private Properties messages = new Properties();

    public Properties getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

}
```

`Properties.class` is just a wrapper for `Map<String, String>` so you can convert it to JSON.

Comment: Will Spring inject all the properties to the messages property?

Comment: Yes, it will inject all properties into this Property instance. One note: you need to start all properties with key `messages`. It will

Comment: I tried but it did not inject anything to the messages property.

Comment: Could you try to create a getter for this property?

Comment: I even add "messages.hello = World" which is a key-value pair that starts with key "messages". It did not work.

Comment: I think this solution would really not work because it is missing annotation to the property messages that's why no injection is happening. If I place @Value("messages.hello"), it will only inject one property, but what i need is all properties.

Comment: Sorry, doublechecked my anwer - my solution worked with custom writted BeanPostProcessor. Updated the default SpringMVC way to do it. You need to create a bean, annotation will not work for whole file loading.

Comment: can you give an example how to use this in the controller then ?